# cuda "rounding modes" of reciprocal functions

Tags: api, math, cuda, intrinsics

Looking at [Cuda-Math-Api documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SINGLE),  functions

- `__frcp_rd`  compute 1/x in a round-down mode
- `__frcp_rn`  compute 1/x in a round-to-nearest-even mode
- `__frcp_ru`  compute 1/x in a round-up mode
- `__frcp_rz`  compute 1/x in round-towards-zero mode

But what do those "modes" mean?  If I were to divide  '1/3'  what would each function produce?

Googling for "rounding modes of reciprocal" didn't return any results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably FP rounding mode.

The exact result is usually between two representable float values, and the rounding mode determines which of the two is picked.  So the difference between 2 rounding modes will be 1 unit in the last place (of the significand aka mantissa), or 0 if they round the same way.

Comment: This is correct. Modern Nvidia GPUs support IEE754-2008 standard floating point, including all the rounding modes and this is how they are exposed